# MPMoviePlayerController stops after four seconds

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to set up a very simple video player. (iOS 5.1, Xcode 4.3.1)

```
-(void)playMedia {
NSString *movieFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movieFile]];

[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
[self.view addSubview: moviePlayer.view];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(playMediaFinished:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:moviePlayer];
[moviePlayer play];
}
```

It works fine when called, but it only plays for four seconds, then a black screen appears.  If I tap the screen during playback, it will play the entire sequence. If I stop tapping the screen for four seconds, the black screen appears.

What am i missing?

Kurt

---

Edited version plays fine.

In the interface file:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) MPMoviePlayerController *myMovieController;
```

In the .m file:

```
-(void)playMedia {
NSString *movieFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movieFile]];

[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;

self.myMovieController = moviePlayer;
[self.view addSubview: self.myMovieController.view];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(playMediaFinished:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:moviePlayer];
[self.myMovieController play];
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're using ARC I believe you need to retain the outer moviePlayer. I just assigned it to a new property myself. HTH

Comment: I'm using ARC, but pardon my ignorance. If I call [moviePlayer retain], I get an error message "ARC forbids explicit message send of 'retain'". Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Got it. As you said, you assigned a property. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Good stuff, glad it worked. Dunno if there's another cleverer way to do the retain in ARC, as you say you can't call retain explicitly, but the property does the job.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is that the player would have to be an instance variable or property of the view controller. 
ie We must use the instance of MPMoviePlayerController

@property (nonatomic,strong) MPMoviePlayerController *myMovieController;

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks. In thinking backwards guess it makes sens. Any way thanks